Use DwmSetWindowAttribute to create rounded-corner window but didn't work
Windows 10, Win32 classic application: I want to use DwmSetWindowAttribute to create a rounded-corner window, but the function did not work, why?

MainWindow = CreateWindow(wxex.lpszClassName, WindowTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      0, 0, nWidth, nHeight, NULL, NULL hin, NULL);
DWM_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE pef = DWMWCP_ROUND;
DwmSetWindowAttribite(MainWindow, DWMWA_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE, &pef, sizeof(pef));
ShowWindow(MainWindow, SW_SHOW);



Check the return value of DwmSetWindowAttribute. Then check the "minimum requirements" section of the documentation.

I check the DwmSetWindowAttitude's result,  E_INVALIDARG One or more arguments are invalid.
@Raymond Chen

If you wait for Windows 12 the odds are Microsoft will have dropped rounded corners anyway.

If history is any indication, it takes about a decade to toggle between rounded and sharp corners.

You say you're using Windows 10, but DWMWA_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE is supported only starting with Windows 11 Build 22000 as official doc says:

DWMWA_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE Use with DwmSetWindowAttribute.
Specifies the rounded corner preference for a window. The pvAttribute
parameter points to a value of type DWM_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE.
This value is supported starting with Windows 11 Build 22000.


Not so perfect alternative solution is using CreateRoundRectRgn.
SetWindowRgn(hwnd, CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, 800, 600, 50, 50), true);

But When using SetWindowRgn，the system assumes that a window with a non-NULL region is a specialized window that does not use visual styles.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cookbook-overview#when-visual-styles-are-not-applied
